# Best practices to use rest & soap together for client android app

Tags: magento-1.7, soap, rest-api, mobile

I am working on Magento based m-commerce android app. In which I have to use both REST & SOAP web api. Because REST api didn't provide all functionality as SOAP. And to use only SOAP api for whole app will reduce app performance and also UX due to overheads and xml.

What is the best practices for doing this thing? Is there any simple option available?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33695/the-soap-or-rest-way/33734#33734

Comment: Why do people keep trying to use these management API's for mobile applications? XmlConnect is made for that.